# Set default value of dropdown menu dynamically

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a dropdown menu with a few possibilities, however on the initial load I want to display the value that's saved in the database for this specific post that is loaded.

I tried this:

```
<select name="standort" id="standort" class="h-full w-full flex justify-center bg-white bg-opacity-95 rounded focus:ring-2 border border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 text-base outline-none text-gray-700 text-lg text-center leading-8" value="{{ $post->Standort }}">

    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="{{ $post->Standort }}">Standort</option>
```

I also tried to leave out the `disabled`attribute but it didn't change anything.

Is it even possible to set it dynamically?

I know it works when I do this:

```
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="{{ $post->type_name }}">{{ $post->type_name }}</option>
```

But the function behind the blade file is that someone can alter for instance the type_name of a post. When I just have it between the option tags then it doesn't get recognized in the request or does it?

Comment: To set the selected option of `<select>` element, you need to set the [boolean attributed `selected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected) on the specific `<option>`. In HTML, a [boolean attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#boolean_attributes) isn't true or false, unfortunately. Instead, it is either there with no value, or there but the the name for the same value. So `<option selected value="2">` or `<option selected="selected" value="2">`